# Changing NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: swift, autolayout

I want to change width of scroll view. First, i did this:

```
var scrollWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then set it:

```
scrollWidthConstraint = contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(scrollWidth()))
        scrollWidthConstraint.isActive = true
```

Then i want to change it like:

```
  scrollWidthConstraint = contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width)
        scrollWidthConstraint.isActive = true
        contentView.setNeedsLayout()
```

However it appears that i did not remove old constraint, i see in log:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000031d7160 UIView:0x7fc92c808120.width == 1333   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000031fcff0 UIView:0x7fc92c808120.width == 933.1   (active)>"
```

How to remove old constraint and update it?

Comment: Are you creating the scroll view programatically or from Storyboard? If it is the latter, then you're better off adding an `IBOutlet` for your specific constraint and modifying that programatically.

Comment: No memory leak for that code? Look carefully at the adresses, you override the access (var) to it and lose the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
scrollWidthConstraint = contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width)
    scrollWidthConstraint.isActive = true
    contentView.setNeedsLayout()
```

creates another constraint  regardless off you re-assign it to the old one   ,  you need

```
scrollWidthConstraint.constant = width
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```